# Non preemptive Earliest deadline first scheduling

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, scheduler, preemption, preemptive

I am working on a task scheduler and I would like to use EDF scheduling. The task set I need to schedule contains only tasks with deadlines equal to their periods and the tasks must be scheduled periodically. The problem I have is that the tasks cannot be interrupted once they have started execution.

I know that the EDF is an optimal scheduling algorithm only when when tasks are scheduled on a single processor preemptively so I was wondering if there might be any tests or constraints I might impose on the tasks to verify that my task set can be scheduled using a non-preemptive EDF.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let e_i the execution time of task i, P_i its period, and e_m=max_i(e_i). Then, you can guarantee that your task set is feasible, if

U = sum_i ((e_i + e_m)/P_i) <= 1

**Justification:** You probably know the Liu/Layland criterion sum_i(e_1/P_i) <= 1. A non-preamtable task can be seen as a blocking to a higher priority task. Blocking time can be considered as additional execution time. The worst case is when a higher priority tasks becomes ready directly after the longest (lower priority) task has started.

**EDIT:**
I've derived the condition above ad hoc. However, it is a sufficient one only. For a more precise analysis, one have to consider that a task can only be blocked by another task with a lager relative deadline, i.e., with respect to the used model, tasks with a longer period, c.f. e.g., [JL00]*, Theorem 6.18.

Thus, for a task set with tasks T_1, ..., T_n with periods P_1 < P_2 < ... < P_n,
one can calculate

```
L'_i = e_i + max_{j=i...n}(e_j).
```

Then, the task set is feasible for

```
sum_i L'_i/P_i <= 1.
```

C.f. [JL00], Section 8.3 on Nonpreemptive Critical Sections.

<sup>* [JL00] Jane W.S. Liu, Real-Time Systems, Prentice Hall, 2000</sup>

Comment: Thank you, It looks like that in order for this test to pass the period of the tasks must be increased by an important amount. Do you know if there are any other tests that might have a lesser impact on the period of the tasks?

Comment: No, there is no general need to increase the periods. However, the (original) load bound is not equal to 1 (as for Lui/Layland). For some special cases (i.e., an execution time is longer than the laxity of another task) you must increase the periods, because the (adopted) load will always greater than one. But this case is a _real_ worst case you can not avoid, unless you make additional assumptions on stuff like relation of periods and arrival phases.

Comment: what's e_m and what do you mean by period? it's arrival time?

Comment: @Mohsin: e_m is defined above: the maximum execution time. Period refers to the periodic (cyclic) task model EDF assumes.

Comment: Do you have some sort of implemention for EDF scheduling algorithm?

Comment: @Mohsin: Take a priority-based scheduler. If a job becomes ready with an earlier deadline, assign a higher priority than the current job and/or lower the priority of the current job. In theory, one need only two priority levels to implement EDF: just ensure, that the job with the shortest (relative) deadline get the higher priority.