# Non-preemptive scheduling of periodic tasks

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, scheduler, preemption, preemptive

I try to decide schedulability of non-preemptive periodic tasks with same priorities. I have found a question on: [Non preemptive Earliest deadline first scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832658/non-preemptive-earliest-deadline-first-scheduling), however the tasks were not periodic. The question is, whether periodic tasks may obtain a higher schedulability bound?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you exactly mean by higher schedulability bound?

Comment: it is like the schedulability test for preemptive RMS by Liu & Layland. If the cpu utilization is below 0.69 i am sure RMS will schedule it correctly. I'd like to have something similar for non-preemptive scheduling.

Comment: The tasks were scheduled periodically in the question you mention